# Ошибка выбора PictureBox при отрисовке изображения

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется класс `CRenderer`, экземпляр которого после создания привязывает к себе определенный `Control` и производит некоторые действия по отрисовке `BackgroundImage`:

```
class CRenderer
    {
        private Bitmap m_bitMap;
        private Graphics g;
        private Control m_cntrl;

        public CRenderer()
        {}

        public void Bind(Control cntrl)
        {
            m_cntrl = cntrl;

            m_bitMap = new Bitmap(m_cntrl.Width - 1, m_cntrl.Height - 1);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(m_bitMap);

            m_cntrl.BackgroundImage = m_bitMap;
            g.Clear(Color.White);

            DrawXYGrid();
        }

        private void DrawBox()
        {
           /*Работаем только с g*/
        }

        private void DrawXYGrid()
        {
           /*Работаем только с g*/
        }

        public void Draw2DPoints(Model._2DPoint[] points)
        {
            /*Работаем только с g*/
        }
    }
```

Таким образом, однотипные действия выполняются на разными Control'ами, в данном случае - это два PictureBox'a.

```
renderer = new View.CRenderer();
renderer.Bind(pictureBox1);

ren2grph = new View.CRenderer();
renderer.Bind(pictureBox2);
```

Затем, отрабатывает ф-ия, которая работает *только с render* (соответственно, с pictureBox1). Но загвоздка в том, что отрисовка идет - в pictureBox2. В чем может быть ошибка ? Может быть нельзя инкапсулировать BitMap в отдельный класс ? Или порождать несколько объектов Graphics ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть второй `PictureBox` надо привязывать ко *второму* рендереру?

```
renderer = new View.CRenderer();
renderer.Bind(pictureBox1);

ren2grph = new View.CRenderer();
ren2grph.Bind(pictureBox2); // вместо renderer.Bind(pictureBox2);
```

Comment: Черт побери ( Спасибо !

Comment: @isnullxbh не за что :).